# stop node server in tmux

Tags: tmux, node.js

I have a vagrant in which one I launch a node server on start.
The node server is started in a tmux session
but when I attach my tmux session and I do a ctrl + c the server is killed but the tmux session is exited.

For example:

```
tmux       #start a new session and go to tmux
npm start  #start my node server
(ctrl + c) #exit my tmux session
```

Is there a way to stop my server without exiting my tmux session ?

Comment: Have you tried `npm stop`?

Comment: nop, the server is launch and I have no access to the terminal, a little like if you did a `tail -f`

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple possible approaches here.

You could try using `set-options` as follows:

`tmux set-option remain-on-exit on`

This will keep your tmux session alive even after the process exists.  Alternatively, you could just add on a `& bash` to the end of your `npm start` as in `npm start & bash`.